# gdb not printing data structures overloaded method <<

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a data structure s which has an overloaded method '<<'. I want to look at this structure using gdb, so I use

```
(gdb)print s
```

However, this does not print

```
cout << s
```

it gives lots more information about the structure s, which fills up many screens. I am not interested in every bit of data in s, I just want to see what is happening  with the information printed by '<<'. How can I tell gdb to only print this information?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to:

```
call 'operator<< (std::ostream&, myclass&)'(gdbcout, s)
```

But GDB doesn't know what `cout` is, so you'll have to provide your own:

```
std::ostream gdbcout (std::cout.rdbuf());
```

And I'm sure you'll have further difficulties besides.  It might be easier to provide a `PrintMe()` method on whatever class `s` is, and then call that from GDB:

```
print s.PrintMe()
```